# Proof of the converse intercept theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $m$ and $n$ are given lines. $p$ and $q$ are two intersecting lines that intercept $m$ and $n$ at $C,D$ and $A,B$. I want to show that $m\parallel n$ iff $\dfrac{OC}{CD}=\dfrac{OA}{AB}=k$.

[image]

I am trying to solve the problem using vectors.

$\vec{OC}=k\cdot\vec{CD}$

$\vec{OA}=k\cdot\vec{AB}$

How to continue?

Comment: Keep in mind that in an iff, you’re supposed to prove both directions. In your attempt, you’ve only shown working for the backwards direction. Now, you want to show that line m is parallel to n. Note that AC = OC - OA. Note, also, that BD = OD - OB. What can you do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering the notation makes the equations slightly easier.

Let $\vec{OB}=k\cdot \vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OD}=l\cdot \vec{OC}$.

Then $\vec{BD}= \vec{BO}+\vec{OD}=-k\cdot\vec{OA}+l\cdot\vec{OC}=(l-k)\cdot\vec{OA}+l\cdot\vec{AC}$

$\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are not parallel and so $\vec{BD}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are parallel if and only if $l=k$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Why $-k\cdot\vec{OA}+l\cdot\vec{OC}=(l-k)\cdot\vec{OA}+l\cdot\vec{AC}$?

Comment: Just write $\vec{OC}$ as $\vec{OA}+\vec{AC}$.